# three.js cube black but i added texture?

Tags: three.js, textures

I tried adding texture to my cube I made using JS/THREE.JS.
But when I open it up in my browser its all black?

This is my code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>My first Three.js app</title>
        <style>canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://rawgithub.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.js"></script>
        <script>
      // revolutions per second
      var angularSpeed = 0.2; 
      var lastTime = 0;

      // this function is executed on each animation frame
      function animate(){
        // update
        var time = (new Date()).getTime();
        var timeDiff = time - lastTime;
        var angleChange = angularSpeed * timeDiff * 2 * Math.PI / 1000;
        cube.rotation.y += angleChange;
        lastTime = time;

        // render
        renderer.render(scene, camera);

        // request new frame
        requestAnimationFrame(function(){
            animate();
        });
      }

      // renderer
      var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

      // camera
      var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
      camera.position.z = 500;

      // scene
      var scene = new THREE.Scene();

      // material
      var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('crate.jpg')
      });

      // cube
      var cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(200, 200, 200), material);
      cube.overdraw = true;
      cube.rotation.x = Math.PI * 0.1;
      scene.add(cube);

      // add subtle ambient lighting
      var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xbbbbbb);
      scene.add(ambientLight);

      // directional lighting
      var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
      directionalLight.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
      scene.add(directionalLight);

      // start animation
      animate();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I used this guide to do it:
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/three/html5-canvas-webgl-texture-with-three-js/

Comment: any console errors maybe? If you are on your local machine, you will need a local server or add some options to your browser
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally

This is necessary due to Cross-Origin Policy of modern browsers.

Answer (score 8):

It might be because of having MeshLambertMaterial which needs ambient light, which you have but it may not be set correctly.  Try using MeshBasicMaterial instead.

Comment: For me this is not working. The box still is completely flat.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the same code you put and **it works perfectly**.

The only thing I've changed is the path to the image:

```
map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/textures/test.png')
```

Double check that the image is located in the current folder and if it is, try with another image (this one works perfect for me: https://aec-apps.com/sites/default/files/styles/app_160_160/public/Screen%20Shot%202013-10-25%20at%2000.28.49.png).

Hope it helps!