# Texture not displayed on object Forge Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures, autodesk-forge

I am trying to display a textured plane with Three.js. I'm working with Forge RCDB.
At first, I managed to display the plane, but instead of being textured, it was completely black... I made some changes and now nothing is displayed anymore...

Here is my code :

```
render () {
    var viewer=NOP_VIEWER;
    var scene=viewer.impl.scene;
    var camera = viewer.autocamCamera;
    var renderer = viewer.impl.renderer();
    renderer.render( scene, camera ); 
  }
```

and in the function supposed to display the textured plane :

```
new THREE.TextureLoader(texture).load(texture, this.render);
tex.wrapS  = THREE.RepeatWrapping   //ClampToEdgeWrapping  //MirroredRepeatWrapping
tex.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping    //ClampToEdgeWrapping   //MirroredRepeatWrapping 
tex.mapping = THREE.UVMapping
```

At the beginning I used loadTexture(). I managed to display my plane, but it was all black, and no texture was applied on it.

Then, I use THREE.TextureLoader().load(), in this case, I believe it is trying to find the image on localhost. The image is downloaded, I can see it on the console.

But now I get these errors :

```
Uncaught TypeError: scope.manager.itemStart is not a function
```

and :

```
Uncaught TypeError: renderer.render is not a function
```

Now the object is not displayed, even in black.

So I think this may be linked to render, but I don't understand how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18633657/three-js-cube-black-but-i-added-texture), and it answers my question partially.

Finally, I decided to keep *THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture()*, and I replaced *MeshLambertMaterial* by *MeshBasicMaterial*.

No need for render.